# Flag rows contributing to the sum criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs, ifs

I have two columns like this:

```
Name  Value
A     1
A     4
B     3 
B     2
B     5
C     6
C     8
C     10
C     4
```

I am doing sumif based on Names but I have a criteria to full fill. Looking from the least values in a name group whenever my sum reaches lets say 5 I want those rows to have a flag 1 or else 0. In this example it should be:

```
Name  Value  Flag
    A     1   1
    A     4   1
    B     3   1
    B     2   1
    B     5   0
    C     6   0
    C     8   0
    C     10  0
    C     4   1
```

The data is random and not in any order and file is dynamic so can not work around by just putting it in decreasing order. I do not have any idea about offset. Could it be done without using offset and only by regular ifs, sumifs etc. Thanks a tonn!

Comment: I don't understand your expected results for the Flag column. Can you clarify one or two? For example, why are the first three values in this column for Name C 0, and the final one 1?

Comment: The increasing order of C values are 4,6,8,10. Now when I start summing up from the least it is 4,10,18,28 I mean cumulative. But my condition which was "5" was met only after the first so I want that as "1" and others as "0". Hope you are clear.

Comment: What if a given Name contains one or more values which occur more than once? Which should be given precedence for flagging in terms of order of summation? For example, what if every entry in the table you give were for Name="A" and Value=1?

Comment: Actually my values are kind of share of a market in a decreasing / or increasing format so it is not the case at all because all values are like 4.2, 5.6, 7.8 summing up to 100 for one name. But I agree that what you mentioned is kind of deadlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can be simplified somewhat, though, assuming you put your chosen threshold (e.g. 5) in `J1` and that, as implied by your reply to my last comment, no one value for a given Name occurs more than once, then, in `C2`, **array formula****:

`=IFERROR(GESTEP(MATCH(1,0/(MMULT(0+(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2)))>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2))))),SMALL(IF(A$2:A$10=A2,B$2:B$10),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2)))))<=J$1)),MATCH(B2,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$10=A2,B$2:B$10),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2)))))),0)`

Copy down as required.

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Instead of J1 I will give the number there. Is it fine?

Comment: This is terrific! But my excel is huge so its overloading it. But yes, this solution is excellent. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ah, yes. That set-up will struggle on large datasets, I'm afraid. I take it you haven't referenced any more cells than actually contain data, hoping to "cover your bases"?

Comment: Yes, I used it on my large data set and instead of J gave the value. The dataset is only 160 rows though. Still for this operation 160 is too much I am afraid.

Comment: I just tested it on a dataset that large (160 rows by 2 columns) and full calculation took less than 0.25 seconds.

Comment: Oh. My excel might be screwed up then, it was taking time but now it is running fine. I guess the processors were engaged that time. Thanks a lot, Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

In column C add

```
=IF($B10<5,1,0)
```

Im assuming the last value is meant to be 0 as the values in C have already passed 5? Try this one.

```
=IF(SUM(A2:INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$10,0)))<6,1,0)
```

Comment: But I have to see the cumulative sum from the least that where it meets the criteria. Kindly see my comment to XOR

Comment: I used this an got 0 against 4 but I want 1 against it in C name

Comment: Since the code is not taking care of the least number first that is the reason it is getting at 4 in the end and sum is turning out to be 24 and then eventually 28 and hence 0 against it. I wanted to take care of choosing the least no as well in the same line

Comment: Could you not sort column B to help it do that or does it need to remain in that order?

Comment: Yes Shawn, The answer from XOR above worked pretty nicely.

Comment: Good stuff. That is an epic formua.

Comment: Yes it is indeed, Epicness! :D